# ComboBox's Selected Value Changed On Lost Focus in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, combobox

I have a datagridview(dgv) with a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn(colLocation)

```
colLocation.AutoComplete = False
colLocation.HeaderText = "Stored to"
colLocation.DataSource = DB.getLocation()
colLocation.DisplayMember = "description"
colLocation.ValueMember = "id"
```

I added the colLocation to dgv.

"descirption" contains Unicode characters. I **can** see the comboBox correctly and choose the item.

The **problem** is when the comboBox lost the focus, the value is changed to first item of the comboBox.

Any suggestion?

**Updated:**

I found out that the ComboBox doesn't change the data when the DisplayMember is in English characters.

It **changes** only when the DisplayMember is in **Unicode chracter**. Any idea for how could solve this? – tunwn 0 secs ago

Answer (score 0):

Your .aspx page should have something like so:

```
<asp:DropDownList Width="90px" ID="ddlExpenseTypes" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlExpenseTypes_SelectedIndexChanged"  DataSource='<%# GetExpenseTypes() %>' SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ExpenseReasonID") %>' DataTextField="ExpenseReasonID" DataValueField="ExpenseReasonID" AutoPostBack="true"  runat="server" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

That is you need a functional call for index changed.  A function call for filling the drop down ist (DataSource) and a function call to set the SelectedValue of the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

Is this DataGridView databound? You haven't specified a value for DataPropertyName, so there's nothing for colLocation.ValueMember's ID selection to bind to.